# Как установить json стиль для окна mainwindow используя библиотеку nlohmann/json

Tags: c++, json, qt

Всем привет, хочу задать json style для своего приложения в qt 6.6.0 cmake на языке c++.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <QMessageBox>
using json = nlohmann::json;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint| Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint);

    std::ifstream f(":/json/styles/Res/json/styles.json");
    json data = json::parse(f);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(QString::fromStdString(data["style"].get<std::string>()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

При попытке запуска проекта библиотека выдаёт следующую ошибку:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::parse_error'
what():  [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 1: syntax error while parsing value - unexpected end of input; expected '[', '{', or a literal

styles.json следующий:

```
{
  "QMainWindow": [
    {
      "title": "MyMarketplace",
      "icon": ":/ico/custom/Res/iconscustom/MyMPico.ico",
      "frameless": true,
      "transluscentBg": true,
      "sizeGrip": "sizeGrip",
      "navigation": [
        {
          "minimize": "pushButtonMinimize",
          "close": "pushButtonExit",
          "restore": [
            {
              "buttonName": "pushButtonRestore",
              "normalIcon": ":/ico/menu/black/Res/iconspack/square.svg",
              "maximizedIcon": ":/ico/menu/black/Res/iconspack/copy.svg"
            }
          ],
          "moveWindow": "headerContainer",
          "tittleBar": "headerContainer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Подскажите как исправить ошибку пожалуйста, спасибо

Comment: В кьюте есть своя реализация парсера json, не надо тащить третьи зависимости - https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/json.html

Comment: @BeardedBeaver исходя из этой документации не совсем понимаю как решить свою задачу(

Comment: что-то я не вижу в вашем json поля style, которое вы пытаетесь достать в коде

Comment: Написал парсер используя методы QT и вкинул в ui в plain text, выглядит всё 1 в 1 как в json. Почему должно быть поле "style"? Поясните пожалуйста, действую по инструкции https://khamisikibet.github.io/QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets/docs/customize-qmainwindow.html или этот гайд актуален только для pyhton?

Comment: Игнорит команду ссылаясь на Could not parse application stylesheet

Comment: Ну то есть у вас на самом деле проблема в том, что надо подкинуть приложению правильный стайлшит, а json это уже сильно вторичное

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: @megorit большое спасибо